# implementing a javascript graph application to the existing admin panel's listing view

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin, flot

I want to implement a javascript graph plot application (ie http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/turning-series.html) to the existing admin view, where the instances of a model at the listing view also showing charts of these items and can be filtered through by using the already  implemented list_filter option which I added at the admin.py of my application.

I would be greatful for any direction, example or already existing tutorial

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the FLOT tutorials they are pretty complete.

- include jQuery
- include flot

Then just follow the [examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/) / [API](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt)

Essentially you "attach" the chart to a container...

```
<div id="myChartGoesHere" style="width:500px;height:250px;"></div>
```

Then populate it with the data you want:

```
<script>
   //data can be points [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]
   var data = [ [3,4], [5,7], [2,9] ]
   //options is an object containing all your desired features
   var options = {
      lines: { show: true },
      points: { show: true }
   };
   var plot = $.plot($('myChartGoesHere'), data, options)
</script>
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for the answer. The main part that confuses my is not js implementation to the raw html but to the django admin panel, like how can I retrieve the data where django lists these model instances inorder to generate the data such as var data = [ [3,4], [5,7], [2,9] ] . 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would look into django admin templates.
http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/ is a good place to start. At the top of the page, do a for loop over all your data, and print it out as a variable to your javascript. I hope this can help you in the right direction.